# Best suite to develop, manage bugs/tasks, share?

Tags: eclipse, twitter, development-environment, jira, mylyn

I am currently trying to package the best suite for a development team. We are naturally thinking about the following as the foundation

- Eclipse
- Mylyn
- Hudson (Jenkins)
- Subversion (Git, Mercurial, ...)

We are not yet sure about the task manager. JIRA is very interesting as it can be bind to Mylyn and Eclipse IDE.

Moreover, we would like to add the services offered by twitter microblogging like sharing expertise, ideas  between persons, groups, teams on certain projects in our development environment.

Confluence seems the next step after JIRA (as proposed by the same company). 
Other tools like internal twitter (I am thinking about [Yammer](https://www.yammer.com/)) and [Social Text](http://www.socialtext.com/) may fulfill our requirements.

Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

No set is complete without Subversion.

Comment: Or Git that is the rising candidate of these times

Comment: True, I'm becoming old fashioned :)

Comment: Yes indeed, I forgot to mention Subversion or even Git.

Answer (score 1):

Some arguments in favor of JIRA:

There is currently an open plugin competition 'Codegeist'.  One of the entries providing a microblogging capability to JIRA
Check out http://codegeist.atlassian.com/entry/166220

JIRA Hero is also very promising - it allows you to introduce the concept of badges to JIRA (comparable to stackoverflow).
http://codegeist.atlassian.com/entry/166416

Francis

Answer (score 0):

Trac is an open source Task Tracker and wiki, it also integrates with Subversion to give you a web interface for your source code:
http://trac.edgewall.org/

You can get a plugin for it called Agilo, which turns it in to a scrum management tool:
http://www.agile42.com/cms/pages/agilo/

You can see an example of what Trac looks like with the agilo plugin here:
https://dev.agile42.com/wiki

The Trac site itself is what trac looks like without the agilo plugin.

I think Jira is more polished than Trac and has better integration with a greater number of tools. I don't know for instance if Trac integrates with Mylyn, so you may have to do a bit more manual configuration than with Jira, but you do avoid license fees.

I for one have found the wiki as usable as Confluence (I actually prefer Trac), and for tracking tasks it's good. It can be a pain if you have to re-organise sprints, but overall it's fully featured, and still an active project.

Hudson has a Trac plugin.

Comment: Having used both Trac and JIRA I would strongly recommend JIRA. There is no comparison - best product out there for task management. Same for Confluence wiki. Most usable clean products in the market at the moment.